# Bash script loop not incrementing

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that inputs 2 -> file#.txt -> newline into my program. However, the script only inputs file4.txt into my program, even though the loop is running 10 times. I'm not sure why this is happening specifically for i=4.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir/ -- bash -c "{ for i in {1..10}; 
  do echo "2"; echo "file"$i".txt"; echo $'\n'; done; } | ./program; exec bash"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` characters are being processed by your original shell, not the shell executed inside `gnome-terminal`. Also, the embedded double quotes are delimiting the `-c` argument, not being passed explicitly to `bash`.

You need to escape the `$` and `"` characters to preserve them.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir/ -- bash -c "{ for i in {1..10}; 
  do echo \"2\"; echo \"file\"\$i".txt\"; echo \$'\n'; done; } | ./program; exec bash"
```

You could also put the command in single quotes, but then you won't be able to embed `$'\n'` in it, because you can't escape quotes inside single quotes. But you can use `printf` instead of `echo`, since it will translate escape sequences itself.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir/ -- bash -c '{ for i in {1..10}; 
  do echo "2"; printf "file%d.txt\n\n" $i; done; } | ./program; exec bash'
```

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Or just `printf "2\nfile%d.txt\n\n" {1..10}` instead of a loop.

Comment: @Shawn I suspect this is a simplification, and the real application may want to do more inside the loop, since this is simply printing a fixed string.

Comment: @Barmar What would I need to change if I want to pass command line arguments to my program like `./program $C1 $C2; exec bash`. I had some arguments that I was passing into my program with the old command which doesn't work with the new single quotes command that I'm now using.

Comment: A better approach in general would be to put everything in a script file and invoke that, rather than trying to cram it into a `bash -c` line.